# How to give different tax percentage for different products

Tags: tax-class

I want to give different % of tax for for products of different attribute set.I know very little about taxation. kindly someone guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your Tax rate information by navigating to `Sales -> Tax-> Manage Tax Zones & Rates` .
Add the tax rule  by navigating to `Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules -> Add New Tax Rule`.
Use above Tax rule while creating your product.

Tax Rate is a combination of place, or tax zone, and percentage. A zone can be a country, state, or zip code.
A Tax Rule states that you pay this amount of tax if you are this class of purchaser, and you bought this class of product for this amount, and are shipping it to this place.
More details: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/creating-tax-rules-magento

Comment: Thank you. But under the option 'default tax destination calculation' in sales->tax in admin panel only '*' symbol is getting displayed under 'Default state' option even after I have selected the country. Should I change anything to have all the states displayed there?

Comment: @Ramya: States are not available for all countries by default. It's available for US though. For other countries you can create tax rates based on zipcode, or you need import states for countries. Check this: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/31/magento-add-state-country-indian-states/